# Filemanagers (nemo, etc) "mount archive/disk/image/etc" mount points

Tags: mount, gnome, file-manager, nemo

When browsing the filesystem I can mount various things: archives `.zip`, `.tar.gz`, images `.iso`, etc. which then appear to be located in:

```
archive://file%253A%252F%252F%252Fpath%252Fto%252Farchive.tar.gz
```

#### Questions

- Where is the real mount point for these files?
- I want to be able to access them from the terminal, is that possible?

Comment: I know this information has been given in other places. It's how I found it. But it took some digging to figure out what to search for and so I've posted this Q&A to help myself and others find it easily in future. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which file manager you are using.

#### GNOME

If you are using `nemo` or another GNOME based file manager it probably uses the [GVfs (Gnome Virtual File System)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVfs) which by default mounts things to `~/.gvfs/` or `/run/user/$USERNAME/gvfs/` directory, where `$USERNAME` is replaced with your username.

#### KDE

If you use KDE you will have to use an alternative mounting command since by default the KDE file manager uses KIO which doesn't make it's mounts available to non-KIO aware programs. [See this forum post](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=108022). However, note that KDE is extremely configurable so it shouldn't be hard to switch `KIO` for `fusesmb`. I haven't done it myself though.

Comment: Note that Nautilus "Disk Image Mounter" is different and I believe mounts things to `/mount/<user>/<disk_name>`